# Do chaotic/lawful casters summon monsters with entropic/resolute templates, or not?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I found something within the [Summon monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) entry on d20pfsrd which doesn't match something on the same page.

Near the top

> When you use a summoning spell to summon a creature with an alignment or elemental subtype, it is a spell of that type. Creatures on Table: Summon Monster marked with an "*" are summoned with the celestial template, if you are good, and the fiendish template, if you are evil. If you are neutral, you may choose which template to apply to the creature. Creatures marked with an "*" always have an alignment that matches yours, regardless of their usual alignment. Summoning these creatures makes the summoning spell's type match your alignment.

At the bottom

> * This creature is summoned with the celestial template if you are good, the entropic template if you are chaotic, the fiendish template if you are evil, or the resolute template if you are lawful; you may choose any if you are neutral.

It looks to me like there are more templates possible depending on your alignment in this bottom wording.

When I went and checked my physical core rulebook, the top wording appeared in both top and bottom. Was there an update or errata for the bottom section, one which was never applied to the top?

Comment: Your question is missing a question. What do you mean to ask of us? The people maintaining d20pfsrd are open to people reporting errors on their pages -- [Report a problem](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/trouble) is the third link in the side navigation -- so if you think this is an error, you might want to send a message their way and let them know. I've had good response in the past doing this.

Comment: I was wondering if there was an errata or something

Comment: I've edited that into your question and given it a revision. Does that match what you'd like to ask?

Comment: It appears to clearify part of what I am asking, but why are you making changes to what I cut and pasted from the entries themselves?

Comment: @Fering asterisks are special characters interpreted by the page renderer as a typographical instruction; doppelgreener simply edited the blockquote so that it would read on this page as it reads on the srd page.

Comment: Did not know that, will try to be more careful when I cut and paste in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

Not an errata, but those templates came after the Core Rulebook and Bestiary were released. On **Bestiary 2** to be exact (pages 292 and 293), which stated that they could be used on summons, but did not say how they could be summoned with the templates.

- [Entropic Simple Template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/simple-template-entropic-cr-0-or-1-1)
- [Resolute Simple Template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/resolute-cr-0-or-1)

> Entropic Creature (CR +0 or +1)
> Creatures with the entropic template live in planes where chaos is paramount. **They can be summoned using spells such as summon monster and planar ally**. An entropic creature’s CR increases by +1 only if the base creature has 5 or more HD. An entropic creature’s quick and rebuild rules are the same.

Cool, so we can summon monsters with those templates, but how exactly do they work? No rules were given on the Bestiary 2, and we still had no rules saying how they worked by then.

Do we apply entropic if we are chaotic, and resolute if we are lawful? What happens if we are lawful good, does the creature obtain both resolute and celestial templates?

Later, on the [Monster Summoner Handbook](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9ela?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Monster-Summoners-Handbook), we got a further expansion on those templates, with some archetypes allowing you to summon only entropic or resolute templates and feats that allow you to apply different templates to the creature summoned.

And added a bunch of new templates based on elements, such as [aerial, aqueous, chthonic, dark, fiery, and primordial templates](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/versatile-summon-monster).

Considering that the archetypes restrict your summoning and the templates available and add more options, but does not allow a caster with no archetype to summon creatures with those templates.

### Herald Caller Archetype

The Herald Caller (Cleric) archetype from the [Monster Summoner Handbook](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9ela?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Monster-Summoners-Handbook) is important because he has abilities that affect summoned monster's templates.

> Divine Heralds (Su)
>
> A herald caller can use summon monster spells only to summon creatures particularly appropriate to her deity. This includes all creatures listed as summon monster options for priests of her deity (see Expanded Summoning for Clerics), creatures whose alignment matches at least one aspect of her deity's alignment, and creatures of an elemental subtype that matches a domain granted by the deity (if any). When summoning a creature that is **normally summoned with the celestial or fiendish template**, a herald caller of a chaotic deity can instead summon it with the **entropic template**, and a herald caller of a lawful deity can instead summon it with the **resolute template**.

Meaning that those templates could not be **normally** applied to summoned creatures. And this also doesn't contradict the previous text from Bestiary 2.

But it allows the caster to be of a neutral alignment, follows an aligned deity, and still be able to summon an entropic or resolute creature. Example: A neutral good follower of Saerenrae (lawful good) would be allowed to summon resolute creatures.

Asking [James Jacobs](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=1298?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#64896) (Paizo's Creative Director) myself, I got this answer on this subject:

> As written, no; those spells only allow for the **summoning of celestial or fiendish creatures**. Obviously, that's because the entropic and resolute templates were invented a few years AFTER we published the Core Rulebook.
>
> Allowing for these two templates to work with summoned creatures is a great house rule if you don't want to use feats or the like.
>
> And no, **you can't apply more than one template to a summoned creature**.

So, from his point of view, it's not unreasonable to allow those templates to be applied as a house rule, but since the books came on different times, they simply couldn't replace what was written on the core rulebook to allow you to summon creatures with the entropic or resolute templates.

Comment: When you say "based on your own alignment" at the end, do you mean that a chaotic good character would summon creatures with the celestial *and* entropic templates? Or that they could choose which template to apply?

Comment: In the final paragraph, do you mean *planar ally* or did you intend *nature's ally*?

Comment: Planar Ally is the text on the template. Nature's ally's list is completely neutral i believe? Nothing on planar ally says it applies a template though.

Comment: @ObliviousSage based on the texts on the Monster Summoner's Handbook, that seems to be the case. We can apply multiple templates if they all apply.

Comment: @ShadowKras That would seem to give a distinct advantage to summoners with extreme alignments...

Comment: Advantages and disvantages aswell. They get DR X/evil or chaos for instance. They count as both aligments and restrictions if he is a cleric.

Comment: The only real advantages are smite chaos/law/good/evil obtained twice and possibly resist energy with one additional energy type. Darkvision and spell resistance won't improve. But yeah we need official clarification on this subject, i opened this thread on paizo's forum asking about that: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2twtv?Summon-Monster-spell-with-multiple-templates#1

Comment: And even if they smite twice, the bonuses won't stack. The source of the bonus is the creature's charisma. But it does allow the possibily of smiting twice per summon.

Comment: Please do not use the term “Rules as Intended” without specific commentary from the authors themselves, or at least significant textual analysis. We do not know others’ intent unless they tell us, and speculating that a given asterion is puts words in the mouths of the authors and may mislead readers here.

Comment: @KRyan is that a restriction on the answer? On the boards, RaW and RaI is used regardless of the author's actual stand on the subject. RaW when the rules are written on the books/errata. And RaI when there is nothing written about it, but by analyzing the rules we can guess the intent of the author. Sometimes by thought elimination. But there is nothing in between.
What would be the middle term here on stackexchange?

Comment: @ShadowKras That usage is problematic and I, for one, will always and without exception downvote it. It has no merit as jargon, since it is misleading and *not* as widely known or consistently understood as you believe, and it harms this site to use it.

Comment: I will simply remove and refrain from using it without a quote from the author then, is that ok?